# Criteria based field level security

Tags: validation, validation-rule, field-level-security

For profile consultant I have billing information is object, client name, status  is field picklist with pending, active, inactive.

I need to set client name field read only if status is active, client name read, write, delete if status is inactive.

Comment: Hi Sgp, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Also, your post does not currently contain a question. Could you please **[edit]** it to ask one?

Comment: Another way to do it would be using record types and page layouts but the validation rule would be much simpler

Answer (score 3):

**Sgp** I think you can use a **Validation Rule** for this scenario. I am can be modified in your org to accomplish what you are looking for.

At the same time, I will strongly suggest that you read the sections indicated by Adrian in order to help you better next time.

Like I said, you can use a **validation rule** to help you accomplishing your business logic. For this example, I'm going to restrict any editing to the **Name** field on the **Account** object for one **Profile**.

> 1. The restriction depends on a picklist value
> 2. This restriction should be executed on one Profile only.

The first thing to do is to find out the Object you want to use for this operation. I will be using the **Account** object.

So I go to the Account's validation rules section by clicking on **Setup**-->**Customize**(*under Build*)-->**Account**-->**Validation Rules**.

If you are going to use a custom object:

**Setup**-->Under Build click on **Create**-->**Objects** and select the correct Object. You should be able to see a section called "**Validation Rules**" after selection your object.

In both cases, you can create a new Validation Rule.

> 1. Give a **Name** to your validation rule.
> 2. Make sure than **Active** is check
> 3. On the Error Condition Formula, we need to add our validation rule.

Like I mentioned I'm going to do this on my Account object. I have one custom field on the account object of type picklist, `Active__c`.
This field has two options: **Yes** and **No**.

> 1. If the value is **Yes**, the Account Name field will not allow
>      changes.
> 2. If the value is **No**, the Account Name field will allow changes.

We need to get the `ProfileId`for the users that we want this rule to be active. If you go to your org's profile page and click on the "**Consultant**" profile, you can get the ID of that profile by copying the id from the URL inside the Consultant profile page:

Something similar to this URL, the ID will be the last section '**00e0Y456000owH2**'.

```
 https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/00e0Y456000owH2
```

Then you need to add the formula:

```
AND($User.ProfileId ='00e0Y456000owH2',
                ISPICKVAL(Active__c, 'Yes'), ISCHANGED(Name ) )
```

> The `$User.ProfileId` is the `ProfileId` for the '**Consultant**'
>   users.
>
> Inside the `ISPICKVAL(yourPicklistField__c,'Active')`.
>
> Inside `ISCHANGED(theRestrictedField)`

This formula will stop changes to the 'theRestrictedField' specified by you if your picklist is set to Active.

Don't forget to insert the **Error Message** in the box bellow and to use the Field where this error will be displayed. Click on **Save** and test your Validation Rule.

Good luck!.